# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber length]:

Tags: ios, paypal, parse-platform

With these lines of code:

```
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Price %@",[self.product objectForKey:@"Price"]);
NSString *string = [self.product objectForKey:@"Price"];
payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:string];
```

my app is crashing with this log:

```
[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The NSLog is returning:

```
Price 96.67
```

Whay is it crashing???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that you have a type problem, most likely with the object at
`[self.product objectForKey:@"Price"];`
My guess is that this object is already an `NSDecimalNumber`, and when you treat it as a string and then call the initWithString method using it, bad things happen

put a breakpoint at:
`payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:string];`

and then type `po [string class]` into the debugger.

This will show you the type of object stored at `[self.product objectForKey:@"Price"];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `string` object isn't an `NSString`. Looks like it's actually an `NSDecimalNumber` - set a breakpoint there and inspect the object. What kind of object is `self.product`?